# how to copy current og:url to data href for FB comment

Tags: facebook, comments

I've build my site with Weebly, but there's a problem when I tried to connect my website comment with FB comments. I was unable to solve for a long time, hope any expert can give me some advice. truly appreciate!

sample blog post: http://www.lifechem.tw/blog/170202

the og:url is:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.lifechem.tw/1/post/2017/02/170202.html" />
```

but the default Weebly FB comment tool is for http://www.lifechem.tw/blog/170202 instead of the current og:url

I've tried as other posts suggested

```
<script>document.write('<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + document.location.href + '" data-numposts="7"></div>');</script>
```

but the result was the same as default Weebly tool.

I'd like to add a site-wide code into the blog footer that can copy the og:url in different blog posts.

truly appreciate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location under which this content is shown in the browser is different than your og:url, so only setting that is likely not going to solve it.

But you can easily select the meta element with that property attribute value, and get the content using something like this:

```
document.querySelector('meta[property="og:url"]').content
```

(If you need support for older browsers that do not support querySelector, you could use a library like jQuery instead, or any other that support the attribute selector.)